# Is there a function that will round my numbers in pandas whilst maintaining my orders?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rounding

I have created a dataframe using pandas and my numbers are in the powers of e-18 etc. As expected and desired. However, all my numbers are rounded to 6 decimal places, I want to reduce this to 5 d.p.

I have tried using the round() function as suggested but this rounds all my minimal values to 0.0. I want the format of 1.23456e-19 for example.

```
data = {'n':n, 'Electron O.Radius (m)|':lithiumorbit (n,me), 
        'Muon O.Radius (m)|':lithiumorbit (n,mmuon), 'Electron Wavelength (m)|':lithiumλ (n,me),
       'Muon Wavelength (m)|':lithiumλ (n,mmuon), 'Electron Energy (eV)|':lithiumUn (n,me)*(6.242e18),
       'Muon Energy (eV)|':lithiumUn (n,mmuon)*(6.242e18), 'Excited Photon Emission (eV)|':Photonemit,
       'Excited Muon Emission (eV)|':Muonemit}
df_=pd.DataFrame(data)
df_.set_index('n', inplace=True)
```

The subsequent output is:

```
Electron O.Radius(m)|Muon O.Radius (m)| Electron Wavelength(m)| 
 \
n                                                                          
1             1.763836e-11        8.530499e-14              1.108251e-10   
2             7.055344e-11        3.412200e-13              2.216502e-10   
3             1.587452e-10        7.677449e-13              3.324752e-10   
4             2.822137e-10        1.364880e-12              4.433003e-10   
5             4.409590e-10        2.132625e-12              5.541254e-10   
6             6.349809e-10        3.070980e-12              6.649505e-10   
7             8.642796e-10        4.179945e-12              7.757755e-10   
8             1.128855e-09        5.459520e-12              8.866006e-10   
9             1.428707e-09        6.909704e-12              9.974257e-10   
10            1.763836e-09        8.530499e-12              1.108251e-09   
11            2.134241e-09        1.032190e-11              1.219076e-09   
12            2.539924e-09        1.228392e-11              1.329901e-09   
13            2.980883e-09        1.441654e-11              1.440726e-09   
14            3.457118e-09        1.671978e-11              1.551551e-09   
15            3.968631e-09        1.919362e-11              1.662376e-09   
16            4.515420e-09        2.183808e-11              1.773201e-09   
17            5.097486e-09        2.465314e-11              1.884026e-09   
18            5.714828e-09        2.763882e-11              1.994851e-09   
19            6.367448e-09        3.079510e-11              2.105676e-09   
20            7.055344e-09        3.412200e-11              2.216502e-09
```

as desired, but one digit too many.

Comment: I agree, that's what I've done, I'm hoping to 'fix' the display aspect, as pandas has formatted my data this way, and I was under the impression that it could be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Set display option:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.5e}'.format
```

Then just *print(df_)*. Of course, this changes only the display format.
Internally all numbers are kept in "usual" precision.

**Alternative**

To display each column with individual formatting, you may use something like:

```
df.style.format({
    'var1': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var2': '{:,.2f}'.format,
    'var3': '{:,.2%}'.format,
})
```

setting column names and their formatting according to your needs.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo Neat solution! Is there a way to do this but keep different formatting for different columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows using [`pandas.DataFrame.round()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
# df is your dataframe
# keeping 5 places after the decimal for all columns
df.round(5)

# keeping different number of places after the decimal
# This will enforce 5, 6, 7 places after decimal for the following columns.
df.round({'Electron O.Radius(m)|': 5,'Muon O.Radius (m)|': 6,'Electron Wavelength(m)|': 7})
```